# Physical Printer going into error when trying to print PDF using Spooled file on remote outqueue on AS400

Tags: java, pdf, ibm-midrange

Physical Printer going into error when trying to print PDF using Spooled file on remote outqueue on AS400

When I try to print to a printer connected to AS400 Outqueue, the request is going to the physical printer but printer always goes into error as below,

```
Paper size of Tray 2 is mismatched.

Select another tray from the following and press [Continue]. 
Paper size can also be changed in User Tools. A4 Plain Paper / Recycled Paper.
```

When I fix the error on printer by selecting a tray, PDF will print fine.
I tried to select different trays and paper sizes in Java program but no luck.

Any thoughts why printer is always going into error for Paper size mismatch?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Regards, Swapnil D.

Comment: Did you look at the parameters for the writer (FORMFEED and SEPDRAWER for instance) and try to change them `CHGDEVPRT ...`

Comment: You'll first need to show us the spooled file attributes plus the *OUTQ definition and the printer specs. It's hard to know what might be fixed if we don't know what all is there.